# Resize Fractions

Tags: fractions, resize

I am using the `\dfrac` command to write proofs, but i get them so small.
How can I adjust the size?

here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\setlength{\inferLineSkip}{6pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    $ \begin{array}{c}
      \dfrac{A}{C}\ \rlap{\textbf{R1}}  
 \end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And i get this result:

[image]

Could you help me please?

Comment: Your image shows a display style fraction (i.e. `\dfrac` works, provided you load `amsmath`, which is missing from your example). How big do you want to make the fraction?

Comment: the letters in the fraction will be the same size as surrounding text, why do you consider that small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `proof` package, adopt its syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}

\setlength{\inferLineSkip}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\infer[\textbf{R1}]{C}{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is an optical illusion that R is bigger than A and C. However, you can use a larger font, which, of course, doesn't really make sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\bfrac[3]{{\large\ensuremath{\dfrac{#1}{#2}}~\textbf{#3}}}
\begin{document}

\bfrac{A}{C}{R1} $\dfrac{A}{C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]